# Динамическое обновление значений в инфоблоке Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть csv файл, в котором содержится нужная информация. Я получаю нужные мне колонки, но при этом обновление значений в инфоблоке не происходит, как поправить мой код?

```
    $id=array();
    $price=[];
    $price_from=[];
    $comments=[];
    $annotation=[];

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $arr[]=$data;
        $length=count($data);      
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ 
            //if($data[$i]!="" or !empty($data[$i])){    
                if($i==1)array_push($id,iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251",$data[$i]));
                if($i==3)array_push($price_from,iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251",$data[$i]));
                if($i==4)array_push($price,iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251",$data[$i]));
                if($i==5)array_push($comments,iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251",$data[$i]));
                if($i==6)array_push($annotation,iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251",$data[$i]));
           // }
        }    
    }
    array_shift($id);
    array_shift($price_from);
    array_shift($price);
    array_shift($comments);
    array_shift($annotation);

    /*echo "<pre>";var_dump($id);echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";var_dump($price);echo "</pre>";*/
    CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'); 
    $el = new CIBlockElement;
    $ELEMENT_ID = $id;  // код элемента

    $PROPERTY_COD = ["PRICE_FROM", "PRICE", "COMMENTS", "ANNOTATION"];
    $PROPERTY_VALUE = [ $price_from, $price, $comments, $annotation];
    // Установим новое значение для данного свойства данного элемента
    $dbr = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), array("=ID"=>$ELEMENT_ID), false, false, array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID"));

    if ($dbr_arr = $dbr->Fetch())
    {
      $IBLOCK_ID = $dbr_arr["IBLOCK_ID"];
      CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValues(
        $ELEMENT_ID,
        $IBLOCK_ID,
        $PROPERTY_VALUE,
        $PROPERTY_COD
      );
    }


    echo "<pre>";print_r($dbr_arr);
    ?>
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вы хотите [добавить новый элемент инфоблока](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php) или изменить инфоблок, добавив новые поля?

Comment: Судя по тексту - вы просто хотите залить из csv-файла данные, однако заголовок о другом. Плюс, код у вас не тот, см. в предыдущем комментарии ссылку на рекомендуемый документацией образец кода

Comment: Я хочу обновить существующие значения в инфоблоке

Comment: Тогда вам в сторону [CIBlockElement::Update](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/update.php) - так вы гарантируете что будут вызываться OnStartIBlockElementUpdate  и OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate

Comment: @AK это можно сделать и с помощью CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValues и всё таки как исправить мой код

Comment: Можно. Только свойств у вас четыре, четыре раза базу дёргать на каждую запись - плохо, пожалейте сервер. Кстати, в $PROPERTY_COD у вас массив, [можно только одно за раз](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/setpropertyvalues.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'); 
$el = new CIBlockElement;
echo "<pre>";print_r($name);

for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
    $PROP = array();
    $PROP[110] = $price_from[$i];
    $PROP[109] = $price[$i];
    $PROP[111] = $comments[$i];  
    $PROP[112] = $annotation[$i];   

$arLoadProductArray = Array(
  "MODIFIED_BY"    => $USER->GetID(), // элемент изменен текущим пользователем
  "IBLOCK_SECTION" => false,          // элемент лежит в корне раздела
  "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP,
  "ACTIVE"         => "Y",            // активен
  );
    $res = $el->Update($id[$i], $arLoadProductArray);
}
```